# Rails 4 Jquery not loading external js (typeahead and jqueryUI)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead

Why isn't rails loading external jquery files: I have the following "require" configured in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
//= require boostrap
//= require typeahead
//= require_tree .
```

I can able to access all the listed jquery files from browser but still the following error shows up:

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Comment: Are you sure you're including the `datepicker` component in your custom `juery-ui` build?

Comment: You have `require boostrap` in there.

Comment: Had to remove //=require_tree . Then everything seems to work